# skb_header_pointer() and pskb_may_pull() -- when to use these API?

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel

The kernel has these two functions, `skb_header_pointer()` and `pskb_may_pull()`.

As far as I understand the code, the first one allows to get a pointer to buffer of length `len` on *any* part of the packet.

On the other hand, `pskb_may_pull` makes sure that the area `skb->data` contains buffer of size passed as a function's argument, and if necessary it will pull the data from page fragments.

Do these two functions can be used equally as long as I need to access transport header in IPv4Ipv6 packet? What is the difference between these two APIs?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you process packets through the *`netfilter`*? What's wrong with [`tcp_hdr()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4.178/source/include/linux/tcp.h#L27) if it's only about accessing the transport header?

Comment: I'm processing packets in TC (traffic subsystem). As far as I understand, `skb->transport_header` which `tcp_hdr()` relies on, may not be set by this time. Besides, in `net/sched/act_*.c ` I see usage of both APIs, `skb_header_pointer` and `pskb_may_pull`

Comment: Yep, it may not be set. That's why I asked if you're using netfilter. In netfilter L3-hooks it's set.

Comment: @red0ct, thanks for your feedback. As far as I can see, based on the kernel code I read, `skb_header_pointer` tends to be slower, since it involves copying. I may be wrong though.